# Generate ROS msg from asn1 or c file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm writing a driver for a VANET transceiver (IEEE 802.11p WLAN) to display vehicles and infrastructures that send CAM/DENM messages. The device redirects all received VANET messages via Ethernet/UDP to my ROS computer.
The specifications for the message structures are in asn1 format. So I generated C-code with the ASN.1 compiler `asn1c` to decode the received UDP packets into C structures. But now I want to publish these structures as ROS messages so I have to create `.msg` files. I don't want to create these messages by hand because the VANET messages contain many nested containers and so on.

Is there a tool to generate ROS msg files from asn1 or c files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261468/generate-ros-msg-from-asn1-or-c-file/) by [fehlfarbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30134/fehlfarbe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2017-05-10

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-05-10**:
I don't think there's a tool to generate ROS msg files from asn1 files, but if you can file an asn1 parser library it shouldn't be too hard to write one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a question I would consider as important as well, and something for which I have yet to find a proper solution.

There is a related question here on ROS Answers already [From structure to message](http://answers.ros.org/question/11828/from-structure-to-message/), however it still requires the availability of ROS message types.

Overall the approach requires the manual creation of multiple (several) message types for nested structs as well as the definition of things like hash functions (ros::message_traints::MD5Sum< MyType >::value()) for the custom type.

---

Originally posted by [madapeti](https://answers.ros.org/users/30333/madapeti/) with karma: 16 on 2017-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0